# What program would allow me to rotate the image using an overlaid grid as reference?

Tags: cropping

I need to straighten (turning clockwise or counterclockwise, 1 or 2 degrees) several pictures of the same place taken during different months of the year. I took them standing on the same spot but because I did not use a tripod there are some -minor- angle differences.

Is it possible to have a visible squared grid while straightening and cropping on Digikam, gThumb, Shotwell, nomacs or Gwenview?

I want to crop them to squares and I think this very simple method will give me the result I am looking for.

Comment: The title of your question isn’t accurate. The question really is about rotating using a grid.

Comment: You can try XNView MP (available for Linux) where you have grid but you should use slider or enter direct the number

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend darktable for this: see the [Crop and rotate module](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/modules.html#crop_and_rotate), which has a grid under the 'guides' option.

However, note that with darktable there's a potentially better way of doing what you need to do: you can rotate to a desired reference line by "drawing" that line on the photo. To quote the manual:

> To use your mouse, right-click, hold it down and draw a line along a suited horizontal or vertical feature; as soon as you release the mouse button the image is rotated so the line you drew matches the horizontal/vertical axis.

Answer (score 2):

### Digikam

The "Free rotation" tool has an "automatic adjust" option.

### Gimp

You can use the "Rotate" tool in "corrective" mode, and tell it to display various patterns of lines that you align on things that should be vertical/horizontal.

In Gimp 2.10, you can also use the "Measure" tool and measure the angle of something that should be vertical/horizontal, and then click the "Straighten" button to straighten the image.